# Javascript database with validation based on Entity Framework entities

Tags: c#, javascript, database, entity-framework, local-storage

Is there a way to synchronize local storage with Entity Framework?

What I'm thinking about is for example the following:

A user is completing a wizard in her browser. All necessary data is stored and validated localy based on the entities and validations defined in Entity Framework. In the last step, all this data is transfered from the browser to the server and saved to the database (by EF).

Is there a library for this? Is it even possible at all?

Comment: Yes this use case is possible. Now you need to tell, how are you planning to do in client, using ASP.NET or JavaScript or any thing else?

Comment: preferably ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement wizard or how to send data to server to persist?

Comment: I am asking if there is a library that can handle offline db and later data persistance to EF

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/).  This will let you create entities in javascript and sync them with EF.